# CSS Animation moving element in unexpected ways

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create a function that moves and hides some text based on where the page has scrolled. If the page is scrolled down past a certain point, the "fadeup" animation is triggered and "#first-header" loses its opacity and moves up (translateY) over the course of 1 second.

Then, if the page is scrolled *up* past the point that triggered the "fadeup" animation to trigger the "fadeup-reverse" animation on the "#first-header" element, which does the opposite of the fadeup animation (giving the element opacity and uses the translateY property in the opposite direction).

However, after the "fadeup-reverse" animation is triggered, it ends with the #first-header element being slightly lower on the page than it was upon page load. Also, triggering the "fadeup" function subsequently makes the #first-header "jump" up to where it was initially located on page load right before the animation triggers it to move up and lose opacity.

My question is, why is the #first-header" element being moved lower than specified once it re-appears after the "fadeup-reverse" animation, and how do I prevent it?

My html:

```
<section id="first-section" class="full-height">
    <h1 id="first-header">First Headline</h1>
</section>
<section id="second-section" class="full-height">
</section>
```

My css:

```
@keyframes fadeup {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
        transform:translateY(-50px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(-50px);
        -moz-transform:translateY(-50px);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-50px);
    }  
}
@keyframes fadeup-reverse {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        transform:translateY(50px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(50px);
        -moz-transform:translateY(50px);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(50px);
    }  
}

.fadeup, .fadeup-reverse {
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.fadeup {
    animation-name:fadeup;
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeup;
    -moz-animation-name:fadeup;

}
.fadeup-reverse {
    animation-name:fadeup-reverse;
    -webkit-animation-name:fadeup-reverse;
    -moz-animation-name:fadeup-reverse;

}
```

My jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
        $('#first-header').removeClass("fadeup-reverse");
        $('#first-header').addClass("fadeup");
    } if ($(window).scrollTop() < 81 && $('#first-header').hasClass("fadeup")) {
        $('#first-header').removeClass("fadeup");
            $('#first-header').addClass("fadeup-reverse");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is appearing below it's initial starting point because the `.fadeup-reverse` animation translates/moves to `translateY(50px)` and not `translateY(0)`. Change it to `0` and the element will go back to where it was.

But you can simplify this whole thing by using a CSS transition, and applying a class that does your `.fadeup` animation, then just removing that class.

```js
var $firstHeader = $('#first-header');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
    $firstHeader.addClass("fadeup");
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 81 && $firstHeader.hasClass("fadeup")) {
    $firstHeader.removeClass("fadeup");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 200px;
  height: 500vh;
}

body:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}

#first-header {
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.fadeup {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="first-section" class="full-height">
    <h1 id="first-header">First Headline</h1>
</section>
<section id="second-section" class="full-height">
</section>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much for your responses Michael Coker.